# VSTS release definition is broken

Tags: git, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I removed an artefact from release definition and now I am unable to edit it.

> TypeError: o.RichContentTooltip.add is not a function
>       at update (

Is there anything I could do now to fix it ?

I am using online vsts

Comment: Since you mention tfs and git, can't you restore the working file from source control?

Comment: I tried to import release definition on vsts online, but nothing really happens, I don't want to delete definition and then import again as then we will loose release history ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is an Error from MS Team. We also have several releases with this error now so I suggest you relax and wait for a fix from MS

Comment: Now it is up and running again!